# Optimizing mysql and apache ovh vps

Tags: mysql, vps, optimization, ovh

My website is 100% mysql php so it gets slowdown and sometimes server shutdown.

I'm using [VPS Classic: The best cheap VPS - $2.99/month - OVH](http://www.ovh.com/us/vps/vps-classic.xml) (VPS Classic 4 - 4 vCores and 8GB RAM).

I want some mysql and apache optimisation for my website so it will be faster. If you have any other ways to speed up my mysql I would be greatful.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

- [MySQLTuner-perl by major](http://mysqltuner.com/)
- [PHP: APC - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php)

Comment: Link-only answers are not appreciated here. Please provide content in your answer and then link elsewhere for more detail if necessary.